# How to apply existing javascript on page for appended or replaced html by ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have display html on page using jquery-ajax call. But javascript on that page not working for html added from jquery-ajax response. I tried "async:false " but this one working for on window load. I want to make it working for Click event as well. 
Is there any solution to use existing javascript for appended or replaced html on click event?

Comment: You need to use delegated event handlers when dealing with dynamically appended content. See the duplicate for more information

Comment: i am using this code on load :<pre><code>function getPage(id, tab_id){Query.ajax({
                    url: "testfile.php",
                    data: 'id=' + id,
                    type: "POST",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        
                        $('#' + tab_id).html(data);
                        
                    }
                }); }  And i want to call this method on click event. On window load existing javascript on page is working. On click event its not.